# macOS Mail: Detect when new email arrives

Tags: swift, macos, email

I'm trying to detect when you have a new mail in inbox (in built-in app) on macOS.
I used sdef to get mail header file and work with `ScriptingBridge`.

Is my idea possible?

```swift
import Foundation
import Mail

class MailMonitor {
    let mailApplication: MailApplication

    init() {
        mailApplication = SBApplication(bundleIdentifier: "com.apple.mail") as! MailApplication
    }

    func fetchEmails() {
        guard let inbox = mailApplication.inboxes?.firstObject as? MailMailbox else {
            print("Unable to get the inbox.")
            return
        }

        guard let messages = inbox.messages?().compactMap({ $0 as? MailMessage }) else {
            print("Unable to fetch messages.")
            return
        }

        for message in messages {
            print("Subject: \(message.subject ?? "No Subject")")
            print("Sender: \(message.sender ?? "Unknown Sender")")
            // You can access other details like body, date, etc.
        }
    }
}

let mailMonitor = MailMonitor()
mailMonitor.fetchEmails()
```

Comment: It might be possible. Does your code work?

Comment: what is `import Mail`? Is this a third party library?

Comment: Does it matter if Mail.app is running and has actually received the message or do you really want to know if a message has arrived for a particular recipient? What do you expect to happen if Mail.app processes a new message and moves it from the inbox before your app executes a new detection loop?

Comment: @Willeke unfortunately the code not working

Comment: @KurtisRader it should work also when Mail.app is not running, i just want to know when new mail arrived that’s all

Comment: If you want to use Scripting Bridge (Apple Events) then Mail must be running.

Comment: @Willeke is it not possible to know when mail notification arrived from notification center?

Comment: I don't know, I'm not familiar with user notifications.